# Multiselect items in view model Grid View (Metro app)

Tags: gridview, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I have a `GridView` and i have set its data template to another view.

What i want is to have a `SelectedItems` property in the view model, that will hold All the selected items of `gridview`.

SelectedItems  field  in gridView is readonly (also not dependency property), hence it could not bound.

Answer (score 0):

I had created a behavior to maintain sync between different item controls.

Behaviors are not supported natively, [WinRTBehaviors](http://winrtbehaviors.codeplex.com/) library is used. it is an Open Source for providing behavior support. This library is excellent, and provides a behavior extension, exactly similar to the WPF framework.

Details are listed in the article 
[Managing Multiple selection in View Model (.NET Metro Style Apps)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/412417/Managing-Multiple-selection-in-View-Model-NET-Metr)